# How to get filepaths recursively in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

I've created the solution below to return all filepaths, but it does only seem to work for one folder. Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong?

```
    public static List<string> GetFilePaths(string dir)
    {
        var dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(dir);
        if (dirs.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (var pwd in dirs)
            {
                return GetFilePaths(pwd).ToList();
            }
        }

        return Directory.GetFiles(dir).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Any reason not to use [`Directory.EnumerateFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571(v=vs.110).aspx)? Simply `Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOptions.AllDirectories)`

Comment: Are you aware that GetDirectories as well GetFiles have overloads that allows you to search subfolders and makes all this recursive approach useless?

Answer (score 2):

You are using `return` after each iteration of the loop. That will cause the function to return in the very first iteration and the rest of it will become useless. Instead declare a `List` in the beginning and then keep adding to it and finally return it.

```
public static List<string> GetFilePaths(string dir)
{
    var result = new List<string>;
    var dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(dir);
    if (dirs.Count() > 0)
    {
        foreach (var pwd in dirs)
        {
            result.AddRange(GetFilePaths(pwd));
        }
    }

    result.AddRange(GetFilePaths(dir));
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're returning from the loop in it's first iteration. You should either accumulate your results in some sort of a variable:

```
var filePaths = new List<string>();
foreach (var subDir in Directory.GetDirectories(dir))
{
    filePaths.AddRange(GetFilePaths(subDir);
}
```

or use LINQ:

```
var filePaths = Directory.GetDirectories(dir).SelectMany(s => GetFilePaths(s));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should populate list for every folder.

```
public static List<string> GetFilePaths(string dir)
{
    var dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(dir);
    var returnList = new List<string>();

    if (dirs.Count() > 0)
    {
        foreach (var pwd in dirs)
        {
            returnList.AddRange(GetFilePaths(pwd));
        }
    }

    returnList.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(dir));
    return returnList;
}
```